# Accessing an Array item after setData in Highcharts when hovering over point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to display data. I am using setData to set a data array that is as such: `newSeries.setData([1393221600000,70,41,"1996-02-24"])'`
The chart ignores the 4th item, which is what I want but I would like to use that item on the tooltip. How can I access that item?

Comment: Tooltip for what? The previous points? Either way, I doubt this is this way to do what you are trying to do. I'm guessing you should either add it to the series or initialize the points as objects.

Comment: I would prefer to use objects but how do I initialize them and then setData?

Comment: `setData({ y: 1393221600000, extraInfo: "1996-02-24"}, ...)`

Comment: `setData( [ { x: 1393221600000, extraInfo:  "1996-02-24" , low: 41, high: 70 }, { ... }, { ... } ... ] );` I'm not sure about high/low, bug I guess you are using same `range`-type series. If not, then simply use `y` instead.